# Modifying a Tkinter button with Arduino return serial data

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to use serial data from my Arduino to modify a button or label created in Python/Tkinter?  This button does control the Arduino via the serial port but I can not figure out how to use an analog input or digital output of the Arduino to send data back to the Tkinter program and then modify a button or label.

Comment: I've never had an opportunity to play with an Arduino but I can't see why you shouldn't be able to say `IF *received data from arduino* == 'whatever you want': label.configure(option=value)`